# CredWrite returns Win32 error code 2 (ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION) "Incorrect function."

Tags: delphi, winapi, credui

i'm trying to call [CredWrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375187(VS.85).aspx), but it is returning [ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681382(VS.85).aspx). i can call [CredRead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374804(VS.85).aspx) to fetch credentials out of the password store, and i can store new credentials by using [CredUIPromptForCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375177(VS.85).aspx).

But i cannot figure out how to get CredWrite to work.

The code i'm using is:

```
var
   Target, Username, Password: WideString;
begin
   Target := 'StackOverflowSomething';
   Username := 'IanBoyd'; 
   Password := 'password69';

   ZeroMemory(@Credentials, SizeOf(Credentials));

   Credentials.TargetName := PWideChar(Target);
   Credentials.Type_ := CRED_TYPE_GENERIC;
   Credentials.UserName := PWideChar(Username);
   Credentials.Persist := CRED_PERSIST_ENTERPRISE;
   Credentials.CredentialBlob := PByte(Password);
   Credentials.CredentialBlobSize := 2*(Length(Password));
   Credentials.UserName := PWideChar(Username);

   if not CredWriteW(@Credentials, 0) then
      RaiseLastWin32Error;
```

And GetLastError is returning 1 (`ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION`)

Is this function incorrect? It's not even returning `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`, it's returning "Incorrect function". What is incorrect?

Is there any sample code out there that calls CredWrite?

**Notes**

- i've tried calling the Ansi version (CredWriteA), same result
- i've tried using `CRED_PERSIST_SESSION` and `CRED_PERSIST_LOCAL_MACHINE`, in addition to `CRED_PERSIST_ENTERPRISE`

Comment: Would vote to close as "no longer relevant" because there is apparently nothing wrong with the code posted, but that option isn't available anymore. Chose "too localized" instead since only Ian knows what really happened.

Comment: Yeah, i wasn't allowed to delete it; and my cursory glance though the list of reasons showed none of the reasons was correct. On the other hand, perhaps the perfectly functional code can be useful to someone else looking to use CredWrite, especially from Delphi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, i figured it out.

And it's not the fault of the API call, or my parameters.

i'm just stupid.

And i want to sulk off, without having to say what i did :(

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this

```
 Credentials.Type_ := CRED_TYPE_GENERIC;
```

Be this instead?

```
 Credentials.Type := CRED_TYPE_GENERIC;
```

Comment: No. :-) Type is a reserved word in Delphi, and so importing a type library converts Type to Type_ instead, and things are remapped internally. Good eye, though. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I am curious, this is for the smart card, right? and you're storing the pin no to the smart card, maybe the attachment/driver is not loaded for the credwrite to work? Perhaps, with a standard defined smartcard hardware/software used by windows will activate the CredWrite function, my guess is that CredWrite is attempting to communicate with something (perhaps a generic API call to a standard function within the smartcard hardware?)...just my thoughts...

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: It's not for a smart card. i'm storing generic credentials.